# select value among other values of a different tha column used for Group by in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

so i have three columns like

```
    company id     project id     approved status
       1                 3              NOT
       2                 4              APPROVED
       3                 5              null
       2                 6              NOT
       3                 7              APPROVED
       3                 8              null
       2                 9              NOT
       2                 10             APPROVED
       3                 11             null
```

i have achieved this using left join now what i want is group the companies using GROUP by along with the condition that the group by should return the value of third col approved_status as APPROVED if any of company id has this otherwise NOT if has otherwise null

so basically i m trying to achieve first order by something like this case when approved_status = 'APPROVED' then 1 else 2 etc and then group by but since mysql does not support group by after order by so what should i do in order to get this result .. help !

Comment: Can you share the output you're trying to get for this sample input?

Comment: You mention that this is the result of a sql statement and not a table. Can you provide the sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select company_id, 
       case when sum(approved_status='APPROVED') > 0 then 'APPROVED'
            when sum(approved_status='NOT') > 0 then 'NOT'
            else null
       end as `status`
from your_table
group by company_id
```

Comment: thanks buddy by the way i just achieved the same also using inner query approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL query performing what you want by counting how many projects are approved for each company, if it is >=1 it returns APPROVED otherwise NOT:

```
SELECT company_id, case when sum(approved_status="APPROVED")>=1 then "APPROVED" else "NOT" end
FROM Projects
GROUP BY company_id
```